# c3js bar chart onclick event getting triggered twice

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

I have built a bar chart using c3js and implemented onclick event on it.
Onclick event is acting weird on it.
I used the word **weird** because sometimes it's working fine as it should but sometimes it's getting executed twice on a click.
I am unable to figure out how to deal with this problem since two days, but no luck :(

Is it c3js problem?? Is there any way or workaround to fix this or handle this kind of situation??

Below is the sample code for generating c3 bar chart with onclick event.

```
var chart = c3.generate({
            bindto: "#" + idActiveDivChart,
            data: {
                json: agg(obj_Json, selectedDimension),
                type: 'bar',
                labels: {
                    //format: function (v, id, i, j) { return "Default Format"; },
                    format: d3.format('$.2s')
                },
                keys: {
                    x: selectedDimension, // it's possible to specify 'x' when category axis
                    value: selectedMeasures
                },
                groups: [
                  [selectedDimension]
                ],
                onclick: function (d) {
                    alert('Hell stuff');
                },

            },
            axis: {
                x: {
                    type: 'category'
                },
                y: {
                    tick: {
                        format: d3.format('$.2s')
                    }
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Trend by: '+selectedDimension
            },                
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a known issue, and happens if you click on or near the boundary of two bars. See https://github.com/c3js/c3/issues/1658.

The way to 'fix' it is to slightly change the function that decides whether a mouseclick has occurred within a bar as below, see the offset value has been changed from 2 to -1. Now clicking on the boundary between two bars will get you no hits rather than two which may be preferable (I couldn't get a value of offset for it to just trigger one). The drawback here is that very, very narrow or short bars (< 3px in either dimension) will not report clicks at all.

```
chart.internal.isWithinBar = function (that) {
        var mouse = this.d3.mouse(that), box = that.getBoundingClientRect(),
            seg0 = that.pathSegList.getItem(0), seg1 = that.pathSegList.getItem(1),
            x = Math.min(seg0.x, seg1.x), y = Math.min(seg0.y, seg1.y),
            w = box.width, h = box.height, offset = /*2*/ -1,
            sx = x - offset, ex = x + w + offset, sy = y + h + offset, ey = y - offset;
        return sx < mouse[0] && mouse[0] < ex && ey < mouse[1] && mouse[1] < sy;
    };
```

Comment: You are really a savior for me. Hope c3Js team figure out something for this. Just asking a favor, please do vote up this question so that it can help others out.